# Как русифицировать справку Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, русификация, справка

Подскажите можно ли руссифицировать справку и аннотацию к ключевым словам в Eclipse? В интерфейсе то я еще могу разобраться , но так как я только учусь программировать, думаю было бы не лишним сделать аннотацию на русском...

Если я выучу английский я заброшу программирование!:)))

Comment: Учите английский. Нет, правда. Качественная документация к практически всему есть **только** на английском.

Comment: либо перейти на 1С.

Comment: @KoVadim: злой вы :)

Comment: я не злой. Можно ещё свой язык написать (не только программирования). Или китайский подучить (заметил, что во многих случаях китайский перевод идет вторым после английского.

Comment: @8toni8: засада в том, что если не выучите, программирование тоже придётся бросать. Короче, учите. Хотя бы на таком уровне, чтобы понимать документацию.

Comment: @KoVadim, китайский не знаю, но в последнее время больше заметна как раз обратная тенденция - китайский идет первым и пока его переведут хотя бы на английский в рунэте уже будет русская версия :-)

Comment: Ну вот и стал я программистом, хотя не могу сказать, что выучил английский:))) Скорее наоборот, то что я знаю на английском, я знаю как раз благодаря тому что начал заниматься программированием:)  Не знаю, может быть у кого-то наоборот было?:))) Сначала активно учили английский, для того что бы начать программировать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть же перевод Eclipse на русский язык, правда в глубочайшем бета.

[Скачивайте и пробуйте](http://www.eclipse.org/babel/downloads.php).

**P.S.** Камрады вам правильно советуют - учить английский. Быть прогером и не знать английского это все равно что быть врачом и не знать латынь.

Comment: Ну я бы не сказал, что медики прям хорошо знают латынь:) Да и знать тех. английский и знать разговорный английский, это все таки разные вещи. Согласитесь? Подскажите пожалуйста, а вы сами где изучали английский?